# What's "creation mode" in the Galaxy S's offical messaging application?

Tags: sms, samsung, mms

If you open the official messaging App, go to menu then settings, there is a setting *"creation mode"* which has the following options (in that order):

- restricted
- warning
- free

**What does this change? Is this documented somewhere?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a [Google search for "mms creation mode"](http://www.google.com/search?q=mms%20creation%20mode) I found [this](http://nokia-samsung-sonyericsson.blogspot.com/2009/12/nokia-e71-review-mms-creation-mode-e.html) (among others) which says:

> • **MMS creation mode** — Select **Restricted** to have your device prevent
>   you from including content in multimedia messages that may not be
>   supported by the network or the receiving device. To receive warnings
>   about including such content, select **Guided**. To create a multimedia
>   message with no restrictions on attachment type, select **Free**. If you
>   select **Restricted**, creating multimedia presentations is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Messages longer than 3 texts in length get sent as MMS (picture messages) rather than SMS (texts), thereby costing more than texts, or being outside your contract (if you have pre-paid texts).

- If you leave this setting on 'Free', this conversion to an MMS will happen with no warning.
- If you leave this setting on 'Warning', you get a brief flash of a warning message on your screen when you type a message that is longer than 3 texts in length.
- If you have it on 'Restricted', you shouldn't be able to type a longer message in one go, but I have to say that my Galaxy Ace is set on 'Restricted' and I have still managed to inadvertently send a long message as an MMS.