# Why does my phone come up with a multimedia message sometimes when I am sending a message

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sms, mms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent my device from automatically converting SMS to MMS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4142/how-can-i-prevent-my-device-from-automatically-converting-sms-to-mms)

Can I turn off the multimedia on my phone .  Why does it come up sometimes when I am trying to send thru a message. When it comes up the massage doesnt get sent thru ???

Answer (score 0):

By default, attempting to send a long text message (usually when the content is larger than 3 text messages), it gets converted to a multimedia message MMS.

If you'd prefer that this behaviour not occur, I'd suggest switching from the default SMS Messaging app to an alternate one like GoSMS or Handcent SMS.

Both free apps have an option that allow a user to send long messages or to chop up a long message into sections that will fit and be sent as individual 160 character SMS messages.

Comment: Yup. GoSMS Pro is a much better option than stock messaging application. Once you start using it, you will never switch back to the default one.